# Adding/push() Values to Ajax POST in jQuery serialize() or serializeArray()

Tags: jquery, serialization, addition

**jQuery**

```
$('#speichern').live('click' , function () {
 //  [a]  var data_save = $('#form_rechn').serializeArray();
    var data_save_ser = $('#form_rechn').serialize(); //[b]
//  [a]  data_save[data_save.length] = {"name":"action","value":"save" },{"name":"total","value": Number($('#grandTotal').text().replace(/EUR/g, ""))};
    var addintional = 'action=save&mysql=update' + '&' + 'total=' + Number($('#grandTotal').text().replace(/EUR/g, ""));//[b]
    var data_save = data_save_ser + '&' + addintional;//[b]
    $.ajax({ 
    type    : "POST",
    cache   : false,
    url     : 'invoice_new_action.php',
    data    : data_save,
     error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
     },
    success : function(data) { 
        $.fancybox(data); 
            }
    });
    });
```

The [b]-part works very well; however, why does not work the [a]-part? This is not pushed:
                `,{"name":"total","value": [..]`

**php Ouput via  print_r ($_POST)**

[b]-version

`Array ( [pnr_item_1] => 1 [pkt_item_1] => HostingXXL [desc_item_1] => 20GB, 1x.de [qty_item_1] => 4 [price_item_1] => 15.5 .... [action] => save [mysql] => update [total] => 62 )`

[a]-version

`Array ( [pnr_item_1] => 1 [pkt_item_1] => HostingXXL [desc_item_1] => 20GB, 1x.de [qty_item_1] => 4 [price_item_1] => 15.5 .... [action] => save )`

Hopefully my problem/question is clear.
What is the best method?
There are better methods to so id?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
$('#speichern').live('click' , function () {
    var data_save = $('#form_rechn').serializeArray();
    data_save.push({ name: "action", value: "save" });
    data_save.push({ name: "mysql", value: "update" });
    data_save.push({ name: "total", value: Number($('#grandTotal').text().replace(/EUR/g, "")) });
    $.ajax({ 
      type    : "POST",
      cache   : false,
      url     : 'invoice_new_action.php',
      data    : data_save,
      error   : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
         alert(xhr.status);
         alert(thrownError);
      },
      success : function(data) { 
         $.fancybox(data); 
      }
    });
});
```

What you want to push onto the array are objects in the form of `{name: "name", value: "value"}`, then they'll be serialized/encoded correctly.  Option `[a]` (the corrected form of it) is generally **much** better than option `[b]`, since `[b]` isn't property encoded, and will fail the moment any invalid character slips in there to mess up your variables.  In this case, because you're in control of the appended content, you're safe...but it's best to go the route that always works: never creating your `data` argument as a string directly.

---

As for the why `[a]` doesn't work:

```
data_save[data_save.length] = {"name":"action","value":"save" },{"name":"total","value": Number($('#grandTotal').text().replace(/EUR/g, ""))};
```

This isn't valid, you can't assign 2 things at once, you either need to do it like this:

```
data_save[data_save.length] = {"name":"action","value":"save" };
data_save[data_save.length] = {"name":"total","value": Number($('#grandTotal').text().replace(/EUR/g, ""))};
```

or this (my preferred method, as used above):

```
data_save.push({"name":"action","value":"save" });
data_save.push({"name":"total","value": Number($('#grandTotal').text().replace(/EUR/g, ""))});
```

....or, use [`$.merge()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/) (a bit more wasteful, but cleaner looking), like this:

```
$.merge(data_save, [{"name":"action","value":"save" }, {"name":"total","value": Number($('#grandTotal').text().replace(/EUR/g, ""))}]);
```

Comment: Is it possible to combine $('#form1').serializeArray() and $('#form2').serializeArray() and send it via ajax?

Comment: @hoerf - oh yes, do this: `var arr = $('#form1').serializeArray(); $.merge(arr, $('#form2').serializeArray());`, then `arr` will have the contents of both, just use it for your `data` argument.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine both the forms and serializeArray

```
$('#frm1, #frm2').serializeArray()
```