# ajax and adding the the serializearray in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, serializearray

How do I make this work? I'm trying to do AJAX post. i'm use to doing .serialize but i want to add two more values and keys to the array. how can I do this easily?

```
        $('#moreprojects').click(function(){
            var skip = $(this).attr('name');
            var more = $(this).attr('rel');
            var param = $('#companies').serializeArray();
            param.push({name: 'skip', value: skip})
            param.push({name: 'more', value: more})
            $.post('projectsmore.php', {param}, function(response){
                $('#projects tbody').append(response);
            })  
        })
```

Comment: view answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449695/adding-push-values-to-ajax-post-in-jquery-serialize-or-serializearray

Answer (score 1):

The way you add the values should be fine. But your call to `$.post` should be:

```
$.post('projectsmore.php', param, function(...
```

(no `{}` around `param`).

Comment: i tried alert(param) and it just returns object Object object Object etc. it's not working with the php.

Comment: *I tried alert(param) and it just returns object Object object Object etc*: That is to be expected, as you have an array of *objects*. When you use `alert`, the argument is converted to a string and the default string representation for an object is `[object Object]`. `alert` is **not** for debugging, use `console.log` instead. The JS by itself is correct. Maybe the error is in your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing problems because of the way that you're injecting the param variable into the $.post.  Because the variable param is already an object you don't need to wrap it with brackets.

So instead of:

```
$.post('projectsmore.php', {param},
```

it should be:

```
$.post('projectsmore.php', param,
```