# how to pass a additional data with form serialized data on ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to pass an additional data with form serialize data on ajax post method?.

below is my code which was using for ajax post,

```
   $(document).ready(function()
     {
       var additional_data=$("#extra_data").val();
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'send_mail.php',
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    });
```

here, how to pass a `additional_data` with `serialize` form data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From jQuery API DOCS

```
The .serializeArray() method creates a JavaScript array of objects

The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation.
```

I think to use `push` , we need to use `serializeArray`

try to use

```
var frmData = frm.serializeArray();
frmData.push({name: "name", value: "test"});


$(document).ready(function()
     {
       var additional_data=$("#extra_data").val();
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'send_mail.php',
        data: frmData,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to push the elements to the existing serialized data.

```
var frmData = frm.serialize();
frmData.push({name: nameofthevariable, value: valueofthevariable});
frmData.push({name: nameofthevariable2, value: valueofthevariable2});
frmData.push({name: nameofthevariable3, value: valueofthevariable3});
$(document).ready(function()
     {
       var additional_data=$("#extra_data").val();
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'send_mail.php',
        data: frmData,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    });
```

Comment: hi, i used ur code but it throwing error `ReferenceError: id_array is not defined`  my code is `var frmData = frm.serialize();
        frmData.push({name: id_array, value: extra_data});`

Comment: It should be frmData.push({name: 'id_array', value: extra_data});

Comment: Observe single quotes around id_array.

Comment: got this error `TypeError: frmData.push is not a function`

Comment: It should work. Please see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449695/adding-push-values-to-ajax-post-in-jquery-serialize-or-serializearray

Answer (score 0):

`serialize()` create a query string of the form. So you can append additional parameters into it.

```
$(document).ready(function()
     {
       var additional_data=$("#extra_data").val();
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'send_mail.php',
        data: frm.serialize()+'&param1='+value1+'&param2='+value2,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

serializearray() can be used to send additional parameters. PFB code for sending additional parameters.

```
var request = $('form').serializeArray();
request.push({name: "kindOf", value: "save"});
```

Ajax call

```
$.ajax({

                    url: "/ST/SubmitRequest",
                    dataType: "json",
                    //contentType: "application/json",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: request,
                    //data: r1,
                    success: function (response) {
                        //Setinterval();
                        //alert("Done...!");
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
```